# Sorting a list manually

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

So basically the user is able to fill a number, that number gets added to a list and once the user pressed a button the list should be sorted without using the `.Sort();` function

```
    public int[] nummers;
    public ObservableCollection<int> alleNummers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        alleNummers.Add(int.Parse(nummerBox.Text));
        listBox.ItemsSource = alleNummers;
    }

    private void sortBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int i in alleNummers)
        {
            //Sort the int's from small to big
        }
        nummers = alleNummers.ToArray();
        listBox.ItemsSource = nummers;
    }
```

I think, I need to make use of a `foreach` loop but wouldn't know what to type.
This is a small homework assignment btw.

Comment: Please use google before putting your question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Just pick the simplest and easy to use copy&paste sorting algorithm you find on Wikipedia...

Comment: If this is homework, then you should have all the information you need (Textbook, Class Lecture, etc.) to at least get started. Then, when you have a *specific* problem with what you are doing, come back and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a implementation of the BubbleSort algorithm. This is one of the slowest but also one of the "easy to understand" sorting algorithms.

```
for (int i = (alleNummers.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (alleNummers[j - 1] > alleNummers[j])
        {
            var temp = alleNummers[j - 1];
            alleNummers[j - 1] = alleNummers[j];
            alleNummers[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to use another one, i mentioned some in one of my recent answers: 
[I want an efficient sorting algorithm to sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653986/i-want-an-efficient-sorting-algorithm-to-sort-an-array/35654326#35654326)

Comment: Chosen as best answer because it's the most understandable.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some algorithms that you can follow to sort your list programmatically [Sorting Algorithms with Code and great explanation](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/170/notes/CSharpHtml/sorting.html)

**Bubble Sort**

```
 public static void IntArrayBubbleSort (int[] data)
  {
     int i, j;
     int N = data.Length;

     for (j=N-1; j>0; j--) {
        for (i=0; i<j; i++) {
           if (data [i] > data [i + 1])
              exchange (data, i, i + 1);
        }
     }
  }
```

**Selection Sort**

```
 public static int IntArrayMin (int[] data, int start)
      {
         int minPos = start; 
         for (int pos=start+1; pos < data.Length; pos++)
            if (data [pos] < data [minPos])
               minPos = pos;
         return minPos; 
      }

      public static void IntArraySelectionSort (int[] data)
      {
         int i;
         int N = data.Length;

         for (i=0; i < N-1; i++) {
            int k = IntArrayMin (data, i);
            if (i != k)
               exchange (data, i, k);
         }
      }
```

**Insertion Sort**

```
 public static void IntArrayInsertionSort (int[] data)
      {
         int i, j;
         int N = data.Length;

         for (j=1; j<N; j++) {
            for (i=j; i>0 && data[i] < data[i-1]; i--) {
               exchange (data, i, i - 1);
            }
         }
      }
```

**Shell Sort**

```
   static int[] GenerateIntervals (int n)
  {
     if (n < 2) {  // no sorting will be needed
        return new int[0];
     }
     int t = Math.Max (1, (int)Math.Log (n, 3) - 1);
     int[] intervals = new int[t];       
     intervals [0] = 1;
     for (int i=1; i < t; i++)
        intervals [i] = 3 * intervals [i - 1] + 1;
     return intervals;
  }

  public static void IntArrayShellSortBetter (int[] data)
  {
     int[] intervals = GenerateIntervals (data.Length);
     IntArrayShellSort (data, intervals);
  }
```

**Quicksort a.k.a. Partition Sort**

```
  public static void IntArrayQuickSort (int[] data, int l, int r)
      {
         int i, j;
         int x;

         i = l;
         j = r;

         x = data [(l + r) / 2]; /* find pivot item */
         while (true) {
            while (data[i] < x)
               i++;
            while (x < data[j])
               j--;
            if (i <= j) {
               exchange (data, i, j);
               i++;
               j--;
            }
            if (i > j)
               break;
         }
         if (l < j)
            IntArrayQuickSort (data, l, j);
         if (i < r)
            IntArrayQuickSort (data, i, r);
      }

      public static void IntArrayQuickSort (int[] data)
      {
         IntArrayQuickSort (data, 0, data.Length - 1);
      }
```

**Random Data Generation**

```
 public static void IntArrayGenerate (int[] data, int randomSeed)
      {
         Random r = new Random (randomSeed);
         for (int i=0; i < data.Length; i++)
            data [i] = r.Next ();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer up this guide as a solution to your question

> Sorting algorithms represent foundational knowledge that every
>   computer scientist and IT professional should at least know at a basic
>   level. And it turns out to be a great way of learning about why arrays
>   are important well beyond mathematics.
>
> In this section, we’re going to take a look at a number of well-known
>   sorting algorithms with the hope of sensitizing you to the notion of
>   performance–a topic that is covered in greater detail in courses such
>   as algorithms and data structures

Introduction to Computer Science in C# [10.4. Sorting Algorithms](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/170/notes/CSharpHtml/sorting.html)

it contains many examples, including  Bubble Sort:

```
public static void IntArrayBubbleSort (int[] data)
  {
     int i, j;
     int N = data.Length;

     for (j=N-1; j>0; j--) {
        for (i=0; i<j; i++) {
           if (data [i] > data [i + 1])
              exchange (data, i, i + 1);
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! this approach will short the list by ascending order.

```
        List<int> lst = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 1, 0, 5 };

        int j=0;

        while (j < lst.Count)
        {
            for (int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if ((i - 1) >= 0 && lst[i] < lst[i - 1])
                {
                    int temp = lst[i];
                    lst[i] = lst[i - 1];
                    lst[i - 1] = temp;
                }

            }
            j++;
        }
```